# Webview (chromium) misses frames for no reason?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have trouble debugging an performance issue on a div with overflow:auto. As you can see in the image below (and read in the the breakdown below that) it looks like the webview is wasting precious time by not delivering frames.

Weirdest thing is that the same content scrolls pretty smoothly on two older devices (Moto G and X 2013, Lollipop 5.1) but shows noticeable framedrops on newer ones (Moto X 2014 (Marshmallow 6.0) and Pixel C (Nougat 7.0)).

[image]

Between 990 and 995ms it does some compositing, rasterizing and gpu stuff. Then it sits idly for 15ms (that's almost an entire frame), updates the layer tree, then waits for another 18ms.

So we've missed ~2 frames by now even when it looks like it should have been able to deliver at least one.

Then it fires a scroll event and gets to chew on the javascript that is tied to that. That takes ~5ms and now it does some painting and compositing, then waits ANOTHER 10ms and updates the layer tree, then more waiting and then, finally, delivers it's first new frame since 990ms.

This entire thing took 66ms but, according to the timeline, the webview used most of that time to sit on its ass. And this is not an exception, I'm seeing this pattern during the entire recording of the scroll.

When I look at a timeline taken from the Moto X 1st gen it looks like the webview wastes a lot less time and tries to deliver frames as often as possible. Sure, it's not doing 60fps all the time but at this point I'm happy it does 40 instead of 20 or even lower.

The obvious question here is "what the hell is happening?" - or maybe more accurate: "why are things (read: frames) NOT happening?"

PS: I've checked the Android System Webview version and all of the devices I tested this on have v52 installed. The only thing I can think of is that the OS is 'causing' this. Did something change since Marshmallow?

**UPDATE**

I've been able to solve most of the lag by relaying most of the onscroll-logic I did to requestAnimationFrame and hide content that is off-screen (with visibility:hidden). But this doesn't really explain why Chrome seems to just skip frames when it's not really doing anything. It seems it has to do with scrolling a large area fairly complex content but I'd expect to see that in the timeline in some form. Instead, it just shows large empty spaces that block frames from rendering..?